# importing csv file in django with django-adaptors

Tags: python, django, django-adaptors

I have installed it, imported it in my models.py, created my CSV class like this:

```
class CsvProvince(CsvModel):

    class Meta:
        delimiter = ";"
        has_header = True
        dbModel = Province
```

But I don't understand how to run the import, in [documentation](http://django-adaptors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#id1) is said to do:

```
>>> my_csv_list = CsvProvince.import_data(data = open("my_csv_file_name.csv"))
>>> first_line = my_csv_list[0]
```

but don't know exactly how/where to run it, if I open the shell (I use PyCharm IDE) it doesn't find my classes (CsvProvince), or could I write it all in a .py and execute it?. But I don't get which imports I should do, and where should run it, inside my Django app?, wherever?...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use django's [shell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api). This will load all of your django settings so you can test or use your models interactively.

```
./manage.py shell

>>> from myapp import CsvProvince  # Replace myapp with your app's name
>>> my_csv_list = CsvProvince.import_data(data = open("my_csv_file_name.csv"))
>>> first_line = my_csv_list[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Django shell in PyCharm (Ctrl+Alt+R > Shell), you'll still need to import the class with a:

```
>>> from <your-app>.models import CsvProvince
```